# Need help resolving an Angular 9 TypeScript Error (TypeCasting)

Tags: angular, typescript, casting

I've updated Angular from 4 to 9 and now, after being able to getting it to work, still getting some errors which I am not able to resolve.

My code:

```
this.getTrades().then( ( trades ) => {
    console.log( trades );
    this.trades = new MatTableDataSource<Trade>( trades );
});

getTrades() {
    let promise = new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
        this.dataService.getTrades().subscribe( ( trades ) => {
            resolve( trades );
        });
    });
    return promise;
}

export interface Trade {
    ID: number;
    UserID: number;
    DateTime: Date;
    Exchange: Exchange;
    BaseCoin: Coin;
    MarketCoin: MarketCoin;
    Price: number;
    Amount: number;
    Total: number;
    Last: number;
    Type: Type;
    Status: Status;
    Symbol: string;
}
```

getTrades() datasource:

```
getTrades() {

    return this.http.get( 'http://localhost:8888/currencytracker-api/json/get-trades.php' ).pipe(
    map( res => res.json() ));

}
```

getTrades() returns a json array with the following data:

```
ID: 1
UserID: 1
DateTime: "2017-12-25T00:00:00+0000"
Exchange: {ID: 1, Title: "BitTrex"}
BaseCoin: {ID: 718, Abbr: "BTC"}
MarketCoin: {ID: 743, Abbr: "XVG"}
Price: "0.000013470000"
Amount: "1019.014328640000"
Total: 0.0137261230067808
Last: "0.000005470000"
Type: {ID: 1, Title: "Limit Buy"}
Status: {ID: 2, Title: "Closed"}
Symbol: "Ƀ"
```

This is the error I get:

**ERROR in src/app/components/trades/trades.component.ts:100:68 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Trade[]'. Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Trade[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.**

**this.trades = new MatTableDataSource( trades );**

Any help understanding this error and resolving it would be very appreciated. Thank you.

**Update**

When I declared the trades variable I did it as:

```
Trade[]
```

Instead I have now declared it as:

```
MatTableDataSource<Trade>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not good practice to subscribe inside a Promise callback. [It might lead to memory leaks.](https://medium.com/@sub.metu/angular-how-to-avoid-memory-leaks-from-subscriptions-8fa925003aa9)

If you need to convert an Observable into a Promise, use [`toPromise()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/topromise)

Try strong typing `getTrades()`:

```
getTrades(): Promise<Trade[]> {
    return this.dataService.getTrades().toPromise()      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more explicit about the types:

Firstly, use the most convenient  overload of [HttpClient.get](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get) that requires a generic parameter and interprets the body as JSON.

> Constructs a `GET` request that interprets the body as a JSON object and returns
>     the response body in a given type.

```
getTrades(): Observable<Trade[]> {
    return this.http.get<Trade[]>( 'http://localhost:8888/currencytracker-api/json/get-trades.php' );
}
```

then, add explicit types to getTrades()

```
getTrades(): Promise<Trade[]> {
    const promise = new Promise<Trade[]>( ( resolve, reject ) => {
      this.dataSource.getTrades().subscribe( ( trades ) => {
        resolve( trades );
      });
    });
    return promise;
  }
```

Even better, drop the conversion to promise, and subscribe directly to the `Observable` returned by the dataSource.

```
this.dataSource.getTrades().subscribe( ( trades ) => {
    console.log( trades );
    this.trades = new MatTableDataSource<Trade>( trades );
});
```

**Update**

Check if you use HttpClient from `@angular/common/http`, and not from `@angular/core`.
The `@angular/http` package was deprecated with the arrival of `@angular/common/http`, and was removed with Angular 8.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/http

> Package no longer supported. Use @angular/common instead, see https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#angularhttp

**Update 2**
Your problems with assignment show that it was always incorrect.
`MatTableDataSource<Trade>` is not `Trade[]`

I strongly believe the reason it worked in your old project is that you used
TypeScript 2.x. Thus `getTrades()` was inferred to `Promise<any>`
With Typescript 3.x `getTrades()` (without explicit typing) is inferred to `Promise<unknown>`

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type

> TypeScript 3.0 introduces a new top type `unknown`. `unknown` is the type-safe counterpart of `any`. Anything is assignable to `unknown`, but `unknown` isn’t assignable to anything but itself and any without a type assertion or a control flow based narrowing. Likewise, no operations are permitted on an `unknown` without first asserting or narrowing to a more specific type.

Comment: getTrades(): Observable<Trade[]> { return this.http.get<Trade[]>( 'http://localhost:8888/currencytracker-api/json/get-trades.php' ); } returns the following message: Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.

Comment: Thank you, that solved that message, but this suggestion         this.dataService.getTrades().subscribe( ( trades ) => { this.trades = new MatTableDataSource<Trade>( trades ); }); is still throwing a message, which is: Type 'MatTableDataSource<Trade>' is missing the following properties from type 'Trade[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 24 more. this.trades = new MatTableDataSource<Trade>( trades );

Comment: This shows that you have `this.trades` field typed as `Trade[]`, and you are trying to assign the value `MatTableDataSource<Trade>` to it. This is impossible - `MatTableDataSource<Trade>` is not `Trade[]`

Comment: Not quite sure if I understand it. I understand Trade is not Trade[], and this.trades is Trade[] (trades: Trade[];). Also, the return value (trades) of dataService.getTrades() is Trade[], if I am correct. But I am not able to get this working: this.trades = new MatTableDataSource( trades ); Tried also this.trades = new MatTableDataSource<Trade[]>( trades );

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208209/discussion-between-lesiak-and-user3004118).